# Laravel - Export carbon null return current time

Tags: excel, laravel

Hello i had an excel export for date and time `checked_at` which suppoused to be null, but when im using `Carbon` format it become like this :

[image]

And here is the data that not using `Carbon` format :

[image]

is there a way for the `null` value to not get the current date when i try to export the excel?, thank you!.

here is my export code in my `export.php` :

```
public function map($data): array
    {
        return [
// $data->traffic_viewed_date,
            Carbon::parse($data['traffic_viewed_date'])->format('d-m-Y h:i'),
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In your case what you need is `make` not `parse` see below:

```php
public function map($data): array
  {
    $dataAsCarbon = Carbon::make($data['traffic_viewed_date']); // returns `null` when argument is `null`
    return [
      // $data->traffic_viewed_date,
      $dataAsCarbon ? $dataAsCarbon->format('d-m-Y h:i') : $dataCarbon,
```

Answer (score 1):

The simplest solution i can think of is

```
return [
    ...
    (!is_null($data['traffic_viewed_date'])) ? Carbon::parse($data['traffic_viewed_date'])->format('d-m-Y h:i') : null;
    ...
];
```

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Answer (score 1):

As the API docs that `parse` will not return null. If you want to return null if the value passed to `Carbon` class needs to be **NULL**

You can use `make` method instead.

```
$thisWillReturnNull = Carbon::make(null); // returns null
$thisWillCarbonInstance = Carbon::make('2021-12-16 10:50:25'); // returns Carbon instance
```